# Link to book in device marketplace

Tags: android, google-play

Anybody knows how to create a link in an Android app to a book on Google Play?

I know that for apps has this format:

```
http://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.earth
```

But I'm not finding the answer for books. Thanks in advance

**Update: Example code**

I'm know using following URL based on @Pedro Oliveira answer

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://books.google.com/ebooks?id=2NYlAgAAQBAJ"));
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Know, android first prompt me to select an app to open the url. It shows me only browser apps (ie chrome). 
Then, when browser opens the url, android prompt me again to select again an app to complete the action, but this times the list includes PlayStore app. 
Know, if I click the app it opens fine.

I am doing something wrong?, I need to pass another action to my Intent?

Answer (score 1):

Change the id for what id you want. Hope this helps.

http://books.google.com/ebooks?id=2Zc3AAAAYAAJ

or

https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=2NYlAgAAQBAJ

Comment: Thanks @Pedro Oliveira, the URL seems to work, but I'm having some new issue. I've updated my question with the problem. Do you know why it is happening or do you know any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pedro Oliveira. Know, at least, let me choose PlayStore app within the list of the browsers. Best than nothing, but I wonder if it is possible to open PlayStore without the prompt like with an app. I give you an upvote, but I reserve the accepted answer to whom may resolve this issue

Comment: That's not currently possible since the Market doesn't own a link to books yet like market:// for apps. You can find more info here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#PerformingSearch