# How do I create a direct link for google play books?

Tags: android, hyperlink, google-play

I understand that the direct link for apps is -> market://apps/collection/

Does anyone know how to make the link directly connect to a book in Play Books.

I tried -> https://play.google.com/store/books/details/...?id=...

It works,but there is a step between to choose Play Store oder Browsers, I would like to link direct to the store.

Linking Products means linking Apps...
http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#q=linking%20books

Thanks

Comment: This was [asked recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810028/link-to-book-in-device-marketplace), but unfortunately the Play Store currently does not support deeplinking to books. More details on what *is* supported, can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html).

Comment: That's what I was hoping not to hear, but ok thanks so far.